# align base of triangle and rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am drawing a process flow diagram using TikZ. My code is the following:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[a4paper, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [queue/.style={isosceles triangle,isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
     anchor=north,shape border rotate=90,draw,minimum width=15mm},
   activity/.style={rectangle,draw,
     anchor=north,minimum width=25mm,minimum height=15mm,
     text width=20mm,align=center}]
  \node[queue]    (tortilla queue) at (0,0) [label=below:queue 1]
      {wait};
  \node[activity] (tortilla station) [right=of tortilla queue]
      {tortilla\\station};

  \draw [->] (tortilla queue.east) -- (tortilla station.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is the output

[image]

The problem with the output is that I want the base of the triangle to be aligned with the base of the rectangle. How do I do this?

I have tried to vary the `anchor`, or to use `yshift` but this doesn't work. Of course I could place the nodes manually, but this would mess up the location of the arrows.

Comment: Do you have a lot of repetition? because finding t he corresponding point on the triangle border is kind of tedious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Position

You could place the rectangle relative to the lower right corner of the triangle, and specify `south west` as the anchor of the rectangle, that is

```
right=of tortilla queue.right corner,anchor=south west
```

Note that the anchor has to be specified *after*  the positioning, as `right=of...` sets the anchor automatically.

#### Arrow

Note also, that to make the arrow horizontal, I've used  `-|`, i.e.

```
\draw [->] (tortilla queue.east) -- (tortilla queue.east -| tortilla station.west);
```

which draws a line from `tortilla queue.east` to the point that is on the intersection of a horizontal line drawn from `tortilla queue.east` and a vertical line drawn from `tortilla station.west`.

If you like, you can get an horizontal arrow from the vertical center of the rectangle by using the `intersections` library to find the intersection of a horizontal line from `tortilla station.west` and the closest side of the triangle.

#### Alternative `queue` style

To get the text more centered in the triangle, you can use the `regular polygon` shape, instead of `isosceles triangle`. This will give the corners different names, the lower right being `corner 3`. So, for example

```
queue/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,draw,minimum width=15mm,inner sep=1pt}
```

#### Complete code

With three different options. Screenshot below.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [queue/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,draw,minimum width=15mm,inner sep=1pt},
  old queue/.style={isosceles triangle,isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
         anchor=north,shape border rotate=90,draw,minimum width=15mm},
   activity/.style={rectangle,draw,
     anchor=north,minimum width=25mm,minimum height=15mm,
     text width=20mm,align=center}]

  % original queue style  
  \node[old queue]    (tortilla queue) at (0,0) [label=below:queue 1]
        {wait};
  \node[activity] (tortilla station) [right=of tortilla queue.right corner,anchor=south west]
        {tortilla\\station};

    \draw [->] (tortilla queue.east) -- (tortilla queue.east -| tortilla station.west);     


  % new queue style     
  \node[queue]    (tortilla queue) at (0,-3) [label=below:queue 1]
      {wait};
  \node[activity] (tortilla station) [right=of tortilla queue.corner 3,anchor=south west]
      {tortilla\\station};

  \draw [->] (tortilla queue.east) -- (tortilla queue.east -| tortilla station.west);


  % new queue style, and arrow to center of rectangle
  \node[queue]    (tortilla queue) at (0,-5.4) [label=below:queue 1]
      {wait};
  \node[activity] (tortilla station) [right=of tortilla queue.corner 3,anchor=south west]
      {tortilla\\station};

  \path [name path=from rect] (tortilla station.west) -| (tortilla queue.corner 1);
  \path [name path=triangle side] (tortilla queue.corner 1) -- (tortilla queue.corner 3);

  \draw [->,name intersections={of=from rect and triangle side}] (intersection-1) -- (tortilla station.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]